# Haskell question about memoization / evalution

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to write a "how to make `amount` with access to coins to denominations `coins`, using the fewest coins" function in Haskell. I implemented this with DFS, which works but is quickly too slow. In Python (my main language) I can memoize the results and have the same algorithm run very quickly. I attempted to do the same thing in Haskell, with minimal success.

I will give a toy version of the problem where I am trying to understand memoization, and then show the DFS that I am actually trying to memoize.

**Toy problem**

From [Haskell Wiki's page on memoization](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization), one way of doing this is to index into an infinite list. A similar [gist](https://gist.github.com/beala/d871ae8397167e7035f218a25ddf87dd#file-fibsmemo-hs-L64).

```hs
memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
   where fib 0 = 0
         fib 1 = 1
         fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)
```

This makes sense to me -- the regular recursive relation calls the index of the memoized list, which gives the value if it has it and can fall back to the helper function. :thumbsup:

A minor modification breaks this:

```hs
memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib n = (map fib [0 ..] !! n)  -- now no longer lazily evaled!
   where fib 0 = 0
         fib 1 = 1
         fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)

-- these are not lazily eval'ed either
-- memoized_fib n = (map fib [0 ..] !! ) n
-- memoized_fib  = (\n -> map fib [0 ..] !! n)
```

If I just wanted to implement the Fibonannci sequence, I could take `!!` has to be left partial as a rule of life and ignore it. I am trying to get a better understanding of this, because my function has a recursion on only one argument, and having `!!` "point-free" is challenging.

**My non-memoized version**

This is the non-memoized code I wrote, which hopefully is self-explanatory:

```hs
import Data.List

smallestMaybeList :: Maybe [Integer] -> Maybe[Integer] -> Maybe[Integer]
smallestMaybeList (Just a) Nothing = (Just a)
smallestMaybeList Nothing (Just b) = (Just b)
smallestMaybeList Nothing Nothing = Nothing
smallestMaybeList (Just a) (Just b) = if (length a) < (length b) then (Just a) else (Just b)


makeChange :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Maybe [Integer]
makeChange 0 _ = Just []
makeChange _ [] = Nothing
makeChange amount coins
  | amount < 0 = Nothing
  | amount `elem` coins = Just [amount]
  | otherwise = foldl' smallestMaybeList Nothing [(++) [c] <$> makeChange (amount-c) remCoin | c <- remCoin]
      where remCoin = [c | c <- coins, c < amount]
```

For my (attempt) at a memoized version, I gave up on recursing on the coins to only use denominations not bigger than the current amount, and have this (which is still eagerly evaluated)

```hs
import Data.List

--smallestMaybeList :: Maybe [Integer] -> Maybe[Integer] -> Maybe[Integer]
smallestMaybeList (Just a) Nothing = (Just a)
smallestMaybeList Nothing (Just b) = (Just b)
smallestMaybeList Nothing Nothing = Nothing
smallestMaybeList (Just a) (Just b) = if (length a) < (length b) then (Just a) else (Just b)

makeChange :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Maybe [Integer]
makeChange 0 coins = Just []
makeChange amount coins
  | amount < 0 = Nothing
  | otherwise = [mch a coins | a <- [0..]] !! (fromInteger amount)

-- this is "make change helper"
mch :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Maybe [Integer]
mch 0 _ = Just []
mch _ [] = Nothing
mch amount coins
  | amount < 0 = Nothing
  | amount `elem` coins = Just [amount]
  | otherwise = foldl' smallestMaybeList Nothing [(++) [c] <$> makeChange (amount-c) coins | c <- coins]
```

I have tried other variations where the helper function was inline / nested, and it did not make much difference.

The idea of indexing into an infinite list for `fib` seemed so much more generalizable than the `zipWith` infinite list trick, but even on a toy problem I am getting stuck pretty much immediately.

Questions:

1. Why does translating from point-free to named variables change from lazy to eager evaluation?
2. Advice on how to memoize my current algo?

Comment: Memoization is storing computation results in a *data structure* indexed by the function arguments. For a fibonacci function, the argument is an integer and the natural data structure indexable by an integer is a list. (Not the fastest one, but will do in a pinch), In your case, the arguments are an integer and a list of integers. What is a natural data structure indexable by `(Integer, [Integer])`? I don't know of one off hand. Perhaps a rose tree of some sort?

Comment: Hmm. The above assumes that you want to cache cache all calls to `makeChange` including top-level ones. If instead you want to memoize just recursive calls within a given top-level call, which is a reasonable simplification, then the answer below will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does translating from point-free to named variables change from lazy to eager evaluation?

It's not about making the program pointfree, but about defining the memoization list outside of the function. It's the difference between creating an list once for all, and having every recursive call create a new list and thus not reuse work from previous calls.

Concretely, for Fibonacci, the operator section desugars to

```
mamoized_fib = let fiblist = map fib [0..] in \n -> fiblist !! n
```

where the list `fiblist` is defined outside of the lambda, so it exists before any argument is provided. If you instead wrote

```
fib n = map fib [0..] !! n
```

then the list is defined inside of the lambda, so the list is only accessible when the function is applied, so every recursive call generates its own new list.

---

The goal is to memoize a recursive function of type `Int -> a` for some `a`, assuming the `Int`s are positive (the argument could be something else, you'd have to use a different data structure than lists). So first you have to rewrite your code to make the recursive function have that type. In particular, you should turn the list of coins into a "global" parameter instead of carrying it around at every recursive call. The actual recursive function can then be defined locally in a `let` or `where` clause.

```
import Data.Function
import Data.Foldable

makeChange :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
makeChange coins = make
  where
    make :: Int -> [Int]
    make 0 = []
    make amount = minimumBy (compare `on` sum) [ c : make (amount - c) | c <- coins, c <= amount ]
```

We want to memoize `make`. Once you have written it as a function `Int -> [Int]`, the process is very straightforward.

1. Put the results in a list

   ```
    makeList = make <$> [0..]
   ```
2. Define (what will be) the memoized function by indexing into the list

   ```
    memoMake :: Int -> [Int]
    memoMake n = makeList !! n
   ```

   Note again that it doesn't matter whether you use an operator section (`(makeList !!)`) or not (`\n -> makeList !! n`), just that the list is defined outside of the scope of the index `n`. (It's only after you inline `makeList` that the operator section makes a difference.)
3. Where `make` was called previously (i.e., everywhere except in `makeList`) change calls to `make` into calls to `memoMake`. Here there are two occurrences (one in the body of `makeChange`, one in the body of `make`).

```
import Data.Function
import Data.Foldable

makeChange :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
makeChange coins = memoMake
  where
    make :: Int -> [Int]
    make 0 = []
    make amount = minimumBy (compare `on` sum) [ c : memoMake (amount - c) | c <- coins, c <= amount ]
    makeList :: [[Int]]
    makeList = make <$> [0 ..]
    memoMake :: Int -> [Int]
    memoMake n = makeList !! n
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much for the detail in the answer. I really appreciate the detail about when the list is generated. One small nitpick in case anyone is copying the answer: I think ``makeList`` should be ``[[Int]]``, as ``make:: Int -> [Int]``.

Still, this was incredibly useful!

Comment: Good catch indeed.